# Multiple outputs from same project

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project in Visual Studio(VS). I'm trying to build this project into 2 executable. The executable merely differ by a pre-processor definition.

- Creating multiple projects with different build options, is an option. But the projects has many files put in different folders. Plus the differences are really small. So I'd rather not do this at least for now.
- Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), another way of doing this would be to write a batch file that uses `cl.exe` to get the job done. However the problem with this is that `cl` takes source files as input and not the project file which means this is even worse than the previous solution. And the higher level `devenv.exe` which takes projects as input does not have an option to pass in preprocessor definitions.

**Note:**
A major downside of using any of the above approaches would be that I'd have to reconfigure if any files is added or removed from the original project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id suggest using same solution with 2 Build configurations and ruining MSBuild for each configuration.

```
MSBuild.exe your.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release1;Platform=AnyCPU
MSBuild.exe your.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release2;Platform=AnyCPU
```

Combined with [Property Sheets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/06/23/inherited-properties-and-property-sheets.aspx) is would be relatively simple way to build and maintain.